# Get entire content of page?

Tags: javascript, html

So is it possible to snag the entire content of a page in its current state. For example, if interacting with a page, via jquery, I've modified the document by either inserting content, or by adding or removing class names. Is it possible to get the markup of this document in its current form from starting html tag to html tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just get the root object in the DOM and call innerHTML to get it all?

Comment: Yes we can! - think I heard this phrase somewhere else

Comment: No wait, that's "We can do it, nothing to it!" - and it's Diego, not Dora. *sigh*

Answer (score 8):

Something like

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

This doesn't include the <html> opening and closing tags

Comment: I think on IE you can use document.documentElement.outerHTML and don't have to add "<html>" and "</html>".

Answer (score 4):

just call $('html').html() using jquery to get page source.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Just a test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            $('#showContent').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var pageSource = '<html>' + $('html').html() +'</html>';
                alert(pageSource);
            });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="showContent" >show content</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That rocks, but is there any way to get at the <html> tags and any other text in the page?  ie: DOCTYPE declarations, etc?

I'm working on a "passive" markup scraper for w3c validation concerns and need to have access to the full, rendered html of the page being displayed.

Comment: I'm also very interested if JS can get the whole _rendered_ page, possibly including form fields with user data typed in. If this is possible, this looks like a huge security concern when it comes to 3rd party scripts, such as ads.